# How to make the react component axios response updated immediately after update/delete?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

Hi i am new in using react and axios. I have try the code for simple user CRUD, when i have successfully update the data, then the page will redirected to index of users (using this.props.history.push). The problem is the data is not immediately refreshed (data in index user is not updated) and need to refresh the page to show correctly the data. I have try the debug, then the componentDidMount, constructor, render called again properly but i see the problem in the axios get users method still return the old data. How to fix that? Thank you.

Here my IndexUser.js

```
// IndexUser.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UserService from './UserService';
import axios from 'axios';
import UserRow from './UserRow';

class IndexUser extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value: '', users: ''};
      this.addUserService = new UserService();
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('http://localhost:4200/users')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ users: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
    userRow(){
      if(this.state.users instanceof Object){
        return this.state.users.data.map(function(object, i){

            return <UserRow obj={object} key={i} />;
        })
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="container">
            <table className="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td>User Id</td>
                  <td>Username</td>
                  <td>Password</td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {this.userRow()}
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default IndexUser;
```

Here my EditUser.js:

```
// EditUser.js


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import UserService from './UserService';

class EditUser extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={user_id: this.props.match.params.user_id, username:'', password:''};
      this.UserService = new UserService();
      this.handleUsername = this.handleUsername.bind(this);
      this.handlePassword = this.handlePassword.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:4200/users/edit/'+this.props.match.params.user_id)
    .then(response => {
       if(response.data instanceof Object){
           for(var key in response.data.data){
               for(var subKey in response.data.data[key])
               {
                  this.setState({[subKey]:response.data.data[key][subKey]});
               }
           }
      }  
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

  handleUsername(event){
    this.setState({username:event.target.value});
  }

  handlePassword(event){
    this.setState({password:event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.UserService.updateData(this.state.username,this.state.password,this.props.match.params.user_id);
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push('/index');
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <div className="container">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <label>
                Edit Username:
                <input type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUsername}  className="form-control"/>
              </label><br/>
                <label>
                Edit Password:
                <input type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePassword}  className="form-control"/>
              </label><br/>
              <input type="submit" value="Update" className="btn btn-primary"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EditUser;
```

Here my UserRow.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import UserService from './UserService';

class UserRow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.addUserService = new UserService();
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.addUserService.deleteData(this.props.obj.user_id);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <tr>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj.user_id}
          </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj.username}
          </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj.password}
          </td>
          <td>
            <Link to={"/edit/"+this.props.obj.user_id} className="btn btn-primary">Edit</Link>
          </td>
          <td>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <input type="submit" value="Delete" className="btn btn-danger"/>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
    );
  }
}

export default UserRow;
```

Here my UserService:

```
//UserService.js

import axios from 'axios';

class UserService {
    sendData(userId, username, password) {
        axios.post('http://localhost:4200/users/add/user', {
            userId: userId,
            username: username,
            password: password
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    updateData(username,password, user_id){
        axios.post('http://localhost:4200/users/update/'+user_id, {
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
        .then(res => this.setState({ users: res.data }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };

     deleteData(user_id){
        axios.get('http://localhost:4200/users/delete/'+user_id, {
        })
        .then(console.log('Deleted')).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
}

export default UserService;
```

This is my user routes server (using express + pg-promise):

```
// userRoutes.js

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var userRouter = express.Router();

// Require User model in our routes module
var pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*options*/);
var db = pgp('postgres://postgres:ragamp@localhost:5433/coba');


//Index User
userRouter.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    db.any('select * from public.\"User\" ORDER BY user_id')
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          data: data,
          message: 'Retrieved ALL Users'
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {

    });
});


//Insert User
userRouter.route('/add/user').post(function (req, res) {
  db.none('INSERT INTO  public.\"User\"(user_id, username, password) VALUES($1, $2, $3)', [req.body.userId, req.body.username, req.body.password])
    .then(() => {
        // success;
         res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          message: 'Insert One Users with username' + req.body.username
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error;
    });
});


//Get one/Edit User
userRouter.route('/edit/:user_id').get(function (req, res) {
    db.any('select * from public.\"User\" where user_id = $1', [req.params.user_id])
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          data: data,
          message: 'Retrieved ALL Users'
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {

    });
});

//Update User
userRouter.route('/update/:user_id').post(function (req, res) {
   db.none('UPDATE public.\"User\" SET username = $1, password = $2 where user_id = $3', [req.body.username, req.body.password, req.params.user_id])
    .then(() => {
        // success;
         res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          message: 'Update One Users with username ' + req.body.username
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error;
    });
});

//Delete User
userRouter.route('/delete/:user_id').get(function (req, res) {
   db.none('DELETE FROM public.\"User\" WHERE user_id = $1', [req.params.user_id])
    .then(() => {
        // success;
         res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          message: 'Delete One Users with username ' + req.params.user_id
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error;
    });
});

module.exports = userRouter;
```

Comment: In your `EditUser.js` you are using this.setState inside a loop in the `.then()` method of your `axios` call. So you are triggering a re-render on the first iteration of the loop, never getting past that. You will want to collate your data into the state you want to set, and then update state afterwards.